# multiple insert in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert, procedure

I've a table `Categories` which has `Skins` and which has `Images`

```
Categories : id, Name
Skin :  id, name
CategorySkins : CategoryID, SkinID
Images : id, name
SkinImages: Skinid, ImageID
```

my question is to save a single `Category` instance with a few `Skins` and those `Skins` with a few `Images`.

I've tried to build insert string dynamically, but I don't like this approach.

P.S. Is it possible to pass data like this:
Catogory with list of skins and with list of images. as list to mysql procedure? 

Or simple is it possible to pass array as a parameter to procedure?

Any suggestions about other way of solving this problem?

Comment: I want to insert this data together and I don't know how to pass it to mysql procedure.

Comment: Why are you skipping thinking about using stored procedures when you have yet to even define the basic means for inserting this data in to the database?  You really need to think about how you are going to map that data structure to your database and what individual queries would need to be done to perform the entire data insert before you even worry about whether you need a stored procedure for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Statement for this issue.

```
stmnt = conn.createStatement();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

stmnt.addBatch("insert statement for categories");
stmnt.addBatch("insert statement for skins");
stmnt.addBatch("insert statement for CategorySkins");
...

stmnt.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
```